# Не находит установленный nodejs в Dockerfile

Tags: python, node.js, docker, dockerfile

Есть проект, который использует связку node js и python. Надо упоковать его в докер. Вроде все делаю правильно, все ставится без ошибок(делаю **docker build** ответ: Successfully built 9e241d7850a6
Successfully tagged server:v0.1)

Когда запускаю: **docker run -p 5000:5000 server:v0.1** вылезает ощибка: **/bin/sh: 1: /bin/sh: [node]: not found**

Пробовал node и nodejs.
Сам Dockerfile

```
FROM python:3.7

COPY package.json /server/package.json
COPY Pipfile* /server/Pipfile*
COPY server.js /server/server.js

WORKDIR /server

ENV PYTHONPATH="${PYTHONPATH}:/proj"

COPY . /server

ENV PATH /server/node_modules/.bin:$PATH


RUN echo "deb https://deb.nodesource.com/node_12.x buster main" > /etc/apt/sources.list.d/nodesource.list \
    && apt-get install wget -yqq \
    && wget -qO- https://deb.nodesource.com/gpgkey/nodesource.gpg.key | apt-key add - \
    && echo "deb https://dl.yarnpkg.com/debian/ stable main" > /etc/apt/sources.list.d/yarn.list \
    && wget -qO- https://dl.yarnpkg.com/debian/pubkey.gpg | apt-key add - \
    && apt-get update -yqq \
    && apt-get install -yqq nodejs yarn \
    && npm i -g npm@^6 \
    && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*


RUN pip install pipenv \
    && pipenv install

ENTRYPOINT ['node']

CMD ['server.js']
```

Пробовал также устанавливать чере:

```
RUN apt-get update -yqq \
&& apt-get upgrade -yqq \
&& apt-get install -y --no-install-recommends apt-utils \
&& apt-get install curl -yqq \
&& curl -sL https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_9.x \
&& apt-get install nodejs -yqq \
&& apt-get install npm -yqq\
&& apt-get install build-essential -yqq \
&& npm install npm@latest -g \
&& npm install
```

Comment: Я в таких случаях все время применяю такой паттерн поиска проблем: если контейнер запускается, подключаюсь к нему в интерактивном редиме(docker exec -it container-name(or id)  bash) и смотрю, все ли верно установилось. Допустим, вы можете зайти в контейнер и попробовать получить версию ноды. У меня есть подозрение, что в вашем случае она установилась не в /usr/bin, а, допустим, в usr/local/bin. Если не найдете, можете попробовать команду find /  -name "node", после чего переместить ее в /usr/bin. (А потом тоже самое прописать в докерфайле)

Comment: @instahipsta282 так он и не запускается) с ошибкой запуск падает

Comment: а можете прикрепить полный лог из docker logs id?

Comment: А, кстати, насколько я помню, apt install называет ноду nodejs, чтобы избегать каких-то конфликтов. Можно либо переименовывать после установки, либо менять у себя в следующих шагах пайплайна обращение. Возможно, причина в этом

Comment: @instahipsta282 нашел ошибку..всегораздо проще)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ошибка оказалась гораздо проще и глупее. CMD,ENTRYPOIN и в принципе Dockerfile не воспринимают одиночные кавычки (').Просто заменил `ENTRYPOINT ['node']` на `ENTRYPOINT ["node"]`

Comment: Отметьте собственный ответ решением.

Comment: @Oxyd, свой ответ только через 2 дня можно принять

Comment: Главное не забудьте, что-б не висело в нерешённых.